# SharePoint publishing site - how it differs from simple site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

The question may sound silly, nevertheless quick search has not revealed anything.

- What is the primary purpose for introducing this distinction?
- How can I check if my site is publishing or not?
- Can I toggle this feature on and off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Content publishing features, approval, check-in check-out etc.

Comment: What is content approval, check-in check-out - this is clear. But what is publishing? I do not see this property in setting; there is no column that displayes the state: published/unpublished, etc. Where ca  I find all this?